# How to render text only after a Promise has been resolved in React Native?

Tags: react-native, promise, async-await, state, rendering

I am trying to dynamically translate some text to be displayed when a user clicks on the translate button, but I can't get it to save my values outside of the Promise. I haven't worked much with Promises and every example only shows console.log, rather than saving values outside of the Promise. I don't really understand how they work. Here is (most of) the code I am trying to fix:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       dynamicTranslate: this.props.dynamicTranslate,
   };
}

// I've tried this method as both sync and async (with await) but neither work
googleTranslate = (key) => {
       const translator = TranslatorFactory.createTranslator();
       // translate returns a Promise
       return translator.translate(key, i18n.locale)
              .then((response) => {return response});
}

renderText() {
    // getting some values....
    
    // this loops through all the feedback information
    for (var i = 0; i < components_feedback.length; i++) {
        let label = (some string);
        let value = (some string);
        // to do: call google translate call here if Boolean(this.state.dynamicTranslate)
          if (Boolean(this.state.dynamicTranslate)) {
                // I am ultimately trying to save the translation string from googleTranslate()
                // in label/value so I can push it into feedbacks
                label = this.googleTranslate(label);
                value = this.googleTranslate(value);
          }
        feedbacks.push({label: label, value: value, type: comp.type})
      }

      return (
           // some stuff
           
           feedbacks.map((feedback, index)) => {
                // some stuff

                <Text>{feedback.label}</Text>
                <Text>{feedback.value}</Text>

                // some other stuff
           });
      );
}

render() {
    return (
    <View>{this.renderText()}</View>
    );
}
```

One of the issues I'm running into is that label/value is a Promise if translation is on. If I try to make renderText() an async method, it is also turned into a Promise which render() can't handle. No idea where to go from here.

Comment: you need a return in your render().

Comment: Just edited it to fix that, but that is not the issue. I just forgot to add it in there when I paraphrased my code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. Solution is to put the loop in an async function that (ideally) gets called on construction. This loop was edited to await the returns and push to local arrays of labels and values then saves those in state. You can compare the length of those arrays to the expected length (compare length of last array being used to be positive that it has finished) and that is how you can know if the Promises have returned. Paraphrased code:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        translatedLabels = []
        translatedValues = []
    }
    this.asyncFunction()
}

asyncFunction = () => {
    labels = []
    for loop
        label = await promise
        labels.push(label)
        //same for values
    end for
    this.setState({translatedLabels: labels})
}

//later
renderText() {
    if (this.state.translatedLabels.length === whatever) {
        // do your stuff as you know the async function has finished
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        {this.renderText()}
    );
}
```